# SqlDataAdapter won't update Record

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I have the following code and is not updating the record to the database.

```
 SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("spInvent",cs);
 da.UpdateCommand.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
 da.UpdateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DisplayNo", displayNo);
 da.UpdateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Q", Q);
 da.UpdateCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

 DataSet ds = new DataSet();

 da.Fill(ds);
 gvInfo.DataSource = ds;
 gvInfo.DataBind();
```

I am getting the error here:

```
da.UpdateCommand.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
```

Comment: are `displayNo` or `Q` equal to `null`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct syntax is:

```
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Sql;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;

SqlConnection cs = new
SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myConnection"].ConnectionString);
if (cs.State == ConnectionState.Closed) {
    cs.Open();
}
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
cmd.Connection = cs;
cmd.CommandText = "UpdateStoredProcedureName";
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DisplayNo", displayNo);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Q", Q);
int result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

if (result > 0) {
    //Your Database is updated. To show it in gridview, you have
    //to select the table and show its data.
    SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand();
    cmd1.Connection = cs;
    cmd1.CommandText = "SelectStoredProcedureName";
    cmd1.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@displayId", 0);

    //In the SelectStoredProcedure, use @displayId = 0 to 
    //show all rows.

    SqlDataAdapter adpt = new SqlDataAdapter();
    adpt.SelectCommand = cmd1;
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    adpt.Fill(ds);
    cs.Close();
    GridViewID.DataSource = ds;
    GridViewId.DataBind();
} else {
    cs.Close();
}
```

Comment: SQLConnection is used to make a connection. SqlCommand is used to execute a query at database. DataAdapter is used to fetch values back from database and DataSet is used as a container by DataAdapter for storing the database values.

Comment: how can I display this in my gridview?

Comment: Answer updated. 
ExecuteNonQuery function can only Insert, Update or Delete from your table, it can't **Select** rows from the table and show them.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem here is that you shouldn't execute your query and then fill your data set, you can just fill your data set, so:

```
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
//updated to explicitly create update command object
SqlCommand update = new SqlCommand("spInvent",cs);
update.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
update.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DisplayNo", displayNo);
update.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Q", Q);
da.UpdateCommand = update;
//don't need this line:
//da.UpdateCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

DataSet ds = new DataSet();

da.Fill(ds);
gvInfo.DataSource = ds;
gvInfo.DataBind();
```

Comment: I am getting the error here. da.UpdateCommand.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

Comment: I've updated my answer to explicitly create the update command and then assign it to the data adapter, try that.

Answer (score 0):

Several things here:

1. You don't sepecify the actual `UpdateCommand`.  The constructor for `SqlDataAdapter` sets the `SelectCommand`.  you need to specify which sproc is used to update data.
2. You don't need to execute the `SelectCommand` or `UpdateCommand` directly - the DataAdapter will do that automatically when you use it to fill the `DataSet` or call `Update()` on it (the GridView may do this for you, depending on how you wire it up).